# How to pass object through NodeJS to FrontEnd

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, node.js, frontend

I did try other online solutions but I'm  pretty bad and wanted a better understanding and also i couldn't make it work:

Im setting up a web app and With NODe js for backend and when this someone makes a get request to "/" i want it to get all of the values from SQL like this:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM customers', function(err, result) {
res.json(result);
```

});
Code When some one makes a get request to "/":

```
//Home route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    (sql funciton here)
   });
});
```

How do i pass the "result" variable to the front end.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

  console.log(result);

</script>
```

All i want is it to print out the array but it says that its undefined.

Comment: You need to use AJAX request from javascript to call that Node.js api and get the response from the server to use that data in your UI

Comment: Ok could you please give me a link or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a request to server. For that you can use `axios` or browsers `fetch` api.

```
axios.get("serverip/").then(res => {
   console.log(res)
}
```

Comment: are fetch and axios similar?

Comment: One is third party(axios) and have to install it and other one is inbuilt(fetch)

Comment: Which one do you recomend and for which reason?

Comment: The `serverip` will be `localhost:3000` and call will look like `axios.get('localhost:3000').then(console.log)`

Comment: You can use anyone no personal preference.

Comment: Agh ok thanks your very much for the response ill try it out :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: If i use      res.render('index', {
        title:'Articles'
   }); is it automaticly conerted to json?

Comment: No, its used to render templates. you can use `res.json(data)` to send json data, do read [this](https://fullstack-developer.academy/res-json-vs-res-send-vs-res-end-in-express/) for more

Comment: ok thanks so much. Ill let you go on with your day. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from server, you need to make an API call. XHR or XMLHttpRequest also allows to interact with servers.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("API response  : ",xhttp.response);
};
var url = <API url>;    /*  http://localhost:3000 in your case  */
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Please note that, if the API call is done from an html not rendered by the server handling the API (server running at localhost:3000 in your case), CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue will arise and the browser will block the request.